How to use DocumentAI to extract data and bring the results to BQ using BQML?
I built a custom extractor in Document AI.
Deployed version : pretrained-foundation-model-v1.3-2024-08-31
    # Create a remote model to register your Doc AI processor in BigQuery.
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `data-dev.iiv.invoice_parse_model`
REMOTE WITH CONNECTION `data-dev.eu.doc_conn`
OPTIONS (
  remote_service_type = 'CLOUD_AI_DOCUMENT_V1',   
  document_processor= 'projects/2887432/locations/eu/processors/e97de02/processorVersions/pretrained-foundation-model-v1.3-2024-08-31'
);

# Create an object table in BigQuery that maps to the document files stored in Cloud Storage.
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `data-dev.iiv.invoice_object_table`
WITH CONNECTION `data-dev.eu.doc_conn`
OPTIONS (
  object_metadata = 'SIMPLE',
  uris = ['gs://iiv/*'] 
);

# Parse documents using ml.process_document 
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `data-dev.iiv.invoice_parsed_table`
 AS 
 SELECT * 
 FROM ML.PROCESS_DOCUMENT(
  MODEL `data-dev.iiv.invoice_parse_model`,
  TABLE `data-dev.iiv.invoice_object_table`
 )
 WHERE content_type = 'application/pdf';

Now, I am expecting a schema with the following fields:
amount, description, quantity and units.
But, first - I do not have any schema defined when i click on invoice_parse_model.
And secondly, instead of amount, description, quantity and units... I simply get the schema of invoice_object_table.
Here are a few screenshots, of how the output looks like & the cell value of ml_process_document_result.
----- the first ss

----- the second ss

I have validated the connector values and model specifications.
I want the table to have the parsed values per field defined in the training schema.

You can build a custom extractor in the Document AI with three steps:

Define the data you need to extract from your documents. This is called document schema, stored with each version of the custom extractor, accessible from BigQuery.

Optionally, provide extra documents with annotations as samples of the extraction.

Train the model for the custom extractor, based on the foundation models provided in Document AI.


Once you have extracted the text from your documents, you can then perform document analytics in a few ways:

Use BigQuery ML to perform text-analytics: BigQuery ML supports training and deploying text models in a variety of ways. For example, you can use BigQuery ML to identify customer sentiment in support calls, or to classify product feedback into different categories. If you are a Python user, you can also use BigQuery DataFrames for pandas, and scikit-learn-like APIs for text analysis on your data.

You can visit this public documentation for more information with regards to BigQuery integration.
You can also use document processing to extract insights from unstructured documents. For example, extracting relevant information from invoice files so it can be input into accounting software.

I do not think this answers my question. I clearly mentioned how I have already trained a custom extractor and connected it to BQ using remote connection. Yet my parsed table does not contain the extracted text - rather it is the object table as is. Thanks anyway!
